# SpriteKit SpriteNode isDynamic

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm fairly new to SpriteKit, and I've been following Paul Hudson's course "Hacking with Swift". On his Project 11, he has this relatively simple spritekit game.

I'm trying to replicate it myself, and I found something interesting which I couldnt explain.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
        background.blendMode = .replace
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 512, y: 384)
        background.zPosition = -1
        addChild(background)
        
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
        
        addBouncer(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        addBouncer(at: CGPoint(x: 256, y: 0))
        addBouncer(at: CGPoint(x: 512, y: 0))
        addBouncer(at: CGPoint(x: 768, y: 0))
        addBouncer(at: CGPoint(x: 1024, y: 0))
    }
    
    func addBouncer(at position:CGPoint){
        let bouncer = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bouncer")
        bouncer.position = position
        bouncer.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bouncer.size.width / 2.0)
        // bouncer.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        addChild(bouncer)
    }
}
```

The code above produces this:
[image: with isDynamic commented out]

Interesting enough, if I enabled the commented code

```
   bouncer.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
```

Then I get the following:

[image: with isDynamic set to false]

My understanding, from Paul's video, is that the 'dynamic' attribute there affects how the 'bouncer' will react to collision with other objects. By setting to 'false', the bouncer will not move. It wont be affected by gravity either. If so, what could cause some bouncers to be rendered at the wrong location (on my first screenshot) ?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: The default value for isDynamic is true, therefore if the edge of the screen is also a physicsbody then i imagine the bouncers have moved up as they have collided with the edge of the screen and can't overlap. The 2nd screenshot you have set the bouncers isDynamic to false and the edge of the screen is static, therefore no collisions can be detected between them and they can therefore overlap each other.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520132-isdynamic